# Rails 4 - many to many relation - not updated and does not add new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I try to adapt my edit action/form and i dont understand but this dont work.

My Models are setup as follows (many to many relation):

### Schema Tables

```
create_table "playlists", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",        limit: 255
  t.string   "description", limit: 255
end

create_table "playlist_media_files", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "playlist_id",   limit: 4
  t.integer  "media_file_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "position",      limit: 4
end

create_table "media_files", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "file_file_name",    limit: 255
  t.string   "file_content_type", limit: 255
  t.integer  "file_file_size",    limit: 4
  t.datetime "file_updated_at"
  t.string   "file_ref",          limit: 255
  t.integer  "duration",          limit: 4
  t.boolean  "encoded",           limit: 1
end
```

### Models

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_media_files, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :media_files, through: :playlist_media_files

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :media_files, :allow_destroy => true
end

class PlaylistMediaFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :media_file
end

class MediaFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_media_files, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_media_files

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :playlists, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

### Params

```
def playlist_params
  params.require(:playlist).permit( :name, :description, :datein, :dateout,
                                    :media_file_ids => [] )
end
```

I need to create a "playlist [new / edit]" form that allows me to add or remove records associated with Playlist. I know I can do something simple with "collection_select", and in fact has worked for me, but what I really need is to add or remove a complete record (playlist_id, media_file_id, position).

With "collection_select" I can only add (playlist_id, media_file_id). In addition, this method does not allow me to associate the same record (media_files) more than 1 time and different "position", the Playlist table.

I'm trying to create an audiovisual library in which I can create playlists to play videos via web.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

EDIT

Now I make test this change but still dont work.

Playlist Controller:

```
def playlist_params
   params.require(:playlist).permit( :name, :description, :datein, :dateout,
                                   { :media_files_attributes => [:id, :playlist_id, :media_file_id , :position] }
      )
end
```

Playlist _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :media_files do |mff| %>
<div style="position:relative; width: 320px; height: 24px; float: left;">
  <%= mff.hidden_field :id %>
  <div style="position:relative; width: 30px; float: left;">
    <input type="text" style="width: 20px;">
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative; width: 250px; float: left;">
    <%= mff.object.file_file_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="delbtn" style="position:relative; width: 30px; float: left;">&nbsp;X</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The div (class = "delbtn") is a jQuery function that removes me the object, so that when saving, this should delete the record when the form is submitted.

Apparently everything works well but not how to eliminate the bdd'm deleting records with Jquery on the form.

The development log shows me the following:

```
Started PATCH "/playlists/1" for 192.168.10.148 at 2015-06-04 18:59:07 -0300
Cannot render console from 192.168.10.148! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PlaylistsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Omk2kng40ZZDFnqN//X3Xt5KDEgPSVzIcgtAq38MrTK5TVnjsd6O36l1Es4uhFG1Qj1tPfEk1uG6Auo0+Xswpw==", "playlist"=>{"name"=>"bol 1", "description"=>"bol 1", "cines_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"4"}}, "media_files_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Grabar", "id"=>"1"}
  Playlist Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `playlists`.* FROM `playlists` WHERE `playlists`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Cine Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `cines`.* FROM `cines` INNER JOIN `cine_playlists` ON `cines`.`id` = `cine_playlists`.`cine_id` WHERE `cine_playlists`.`playlist_id` = 1 AND `cines`.`id` IN (1, 4)
  MediaFile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `media_files`.* FROM `media_files` INNER JOIN `playlist_media_files` ON `media_files`.`id` = `playlist_media_files`.`media_file_id` WHERE `playlist_media_files`.`playlist_id` = 1 AND `media_files`.`id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://boleteria.web/playlists/1
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Please Help me.
Thanks.

EDIT: This is my temporary solution.

```
<%= f.fields_for :playlist_media_files do |pmf| %>
  <div>
    <%= pmf.hidden_field :media_file_id %>
    <% if (! pmf.object.media_file_id.nil?) %>
    <%= @playlist.media_files.find(pmf.object.media_file_id).file_file_name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= pmf.link_to_remove "+", :class => "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the nested_form gem linked here I use it for parent child relationships. https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form

Comment: I'll try the gem you mention me Ryan. Thanks.

Anyway, my intention was to understand its operation and to create something more tailored, but I think that would reinvent the wheel.

Thank you.

Comment: How i can use this code :
`<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
      <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
      <%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %>`

But i need to use "collection_select" instead of "text_field".

Comment: I have created a quick gist on Github. In the nested form you use any of the form helpers available to you in Rails, you are not just bound text fields. I have a sample here. This willl allow you to add and remove media files from a playlist on the fly. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rebelweb/ce795b9f1f1f0fb4a3cd) also there are a couple old RailsCasts discussing this [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I try your code but this throw me a error here `<%= ff.collection_select :media_file_id, MediaFile.all, :id, :name, {}, {} %>` and the error is: `undefined method `media_file_id' for #<MediaFile:0x0000000632cd68>`. My temporary solution is in the main post.

Comment: Okay I see the issue now, you will want to accept nested attributes for playlist_media_files not media_files in your model, because you want to create the relation between the playlist and media_files. The way your model is setup you will create a new media file but no link between them. If you are needing to create the media file you may be able to do that as nested attribute of the playlist_media_files, but i would not recommend doing that. Also, don't for get to update strong parameters, to allow the attributes for the playlist_media_files instead of media_files.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I understand that is not the best way and therefore carry a time searching for it. I need to do this because the intermediate "playlist_media_files" table besides having the golf association between "playlist" and "media_file" has a field called "position". As this field is in the "playlist_media_files" table I can not (or have not achieved) use the traditional way that do not have access to this field.

How else could do this? What is the best way to create a relationship between tables and also manage an additional field in the relationship table. 

A better way?

Thank you.